# Promoted properties not restored?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I'm using the promoted activity (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff642473.aspx) to store information needed to track a workflow.
During execution values are correctly stored and I can query them using the view but, if the workflow is persisted, the view becomes empty and I can't find information anymore.

Can someone explain me how to keep those values until the natural completion of the workflow?

Thanks

**update**

a few more details

- I'm using IIS to store workflows
- I promote values at the beginning of the workflow and I wouldn't like to do it again on every persistence property (this was the first workaround I thought)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time a workflow is persisted the **complete** state is persisted. There is no incremental addition. So by not adding the promoted properties on subsequent persists you are effectively removing them from the instance store.

Comment: Thanks. Does it mean that I have to explicitly promote activities before each persistence point or is there a different solution? Maybe should I use a custom extension and remove the PromoteValue activities?

Comment: Normally I use a workflow extension that derives from PersistenceParticipant and holds the state between different persist actions.

Comment: Could you please be more specific for the sentence 'holds the state between different persist actions'? Thanks

Comment: What I mean is I store whatever needs to be persisted in a local store, typically a dictionary, and add that to the readWriteValues collection in the CollectValues() function. See the message in this example: http://xhinker.com/post/WF4Promote-persistence-Data.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't solve the problem completely. Anyway, I noticed that promoted values disappear from my custom views when the WriteOnlyPrimitiveDataProperties is null in the Instances view. Also CurrentMachine is not NULL in such case. Could this help finding the problem?

Comment: Essentially, I'm getting all properties from workflow service of type A (for which I defined promotion name X), but properties for workflow services of type B (for which I defines promotion name Y) are deleted when the WriteOnlyPrimitiveDataProperties becomes null. Anyway...is it a valid scenario? can I define multiple promotion sets?

Comment: After that observation, I looked the code again and in the PersistentParticipant I had this:
protected override void CollectValues(out IDictionary<XName, object> readWriteValues, out IDictionary<XName, object> writeOnlyValues)
        {
            readWriteValues = null;
            writeOnlyValues = this.promotedProperties;
        }
I changed it assigning the properties to the readWriteValues (and null to writeOnlyValues) and now everything is "persistently persisted"

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem.
In the web.config I was adding my extension after the  element, but order matters.

My configuration looks like this now:

..

Everythings works fine now and promoted values are always available.